# How do I access the name field from my CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

My CSV looks like

```
User,Location                                                                          
Louis.Smith,CH
```

I can use a Cmd-Let to show me users from the file

```
Import-Csv "decommisioned_users.csv"| Where-Object{$_.Location -match "CH"}
```

I want to move folders to another folder

So in the above example,

We would create a String that looks like

```
F:\Users\louis.smith
```

and move that folder to

```
F:\ArchivedUsers\louis.smith
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get "louis.smith" from my CSV file (1st column)

Comment: Did you delete your last question and reask? My comments are more or less the same. Did you look at examples of using `Import-CSV`?

Comment: `Import-Csv "decommissioned_users.csv" | Where-Object { $_.Location -eq "CH" } | ForEach-Object { Move-Object F:\Users\$($_.User) F:\ArchivedUsers\$($_.User) -WhatIf }`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart You are missing some brackets for the `for`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart This is an answer.  It may need some brackets as Matt suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ForEach-Object`. Example:

```
Import-Csv "decommissioned_users.csv" | Where-Object { $_.Location -eq "CH" } | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Object F:\Users\$($_.User) F:\ArchivedUsers\$($_.User) -WhatIf
}
```

Of course, remove `-WhatIf` to actually run the command.